# Template base constructor call in member initialization list error

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, compiler-errors, g++

I have a base class that looks like the following:

```
template<typename T>
class Base
{
   public:
      Base(int someValue);

      virtual T someFunc() =0;
};

template<typename T>
Base<T>::Base(int someValue)
{}
```

And then the following:

```
#include "base.hpp"

class Foo
   : public Base<Foo>
{
   public:
      Foo(int someValue);

      virtual Foo someFunc();
};

Foo::Foo(int someValue)
   : Base(someValue)
{}
```

I get the following error from gcc 4.2.1.

> error: class ‘Foo’ does not have any field named ‘Base’

I should mention this compiles fine on my Fedora box which is running gcc 4.6.2. This error occurs when compiling on my os x Lion machine.

EDIT

Problem seems to be that I am not indicating type of template in the Foo class when calling the constructor. The following fixes the error in os x.

```
: Base<Foo>(someValue, parent)
```

EDIT

Yes this does look like a bug. What I mentioned before fixes the error under os x and code compiles fine in fedora with that fix. Will go and see if there is an update to gcc in os x.

Comment: [Qt can be abstracted out from this completely.](http://ideone.com/tSWdI)

Comment: Dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829040/scope-problems-in-template-c

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First:

> `[C++11: 12.6.2/3]:` A *mem-initializer-list* can initialize a base class using any *class-or-decltype* that denotes that base class type.
>
> [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> struct A { A(); };
> typedef A global_A;
> struct B { };
> struct C: public A, public B { C(); };
> C::C(): global_A() { } // mem-initializer for base A
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

And `Base` should be a valid *injected-class-name* for the base here (that is, you can use it in place of `Base<T>`):

> `[C++11: 14.6.1/1]:` **Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an *injected-class-name* (Clause 9). The *injected-class-name* can be used as a *template-name* or a *type-name*.** When it is used with a *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a template *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the *elaborated-type-specifier*
>   of a friend class template declaration, it refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, **it is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.**

> `[C++11: 14.6.1/3]:` The *injected-class-name* of a class template or class template specialization can be used either as a *template-name* or a *type-name* wherever it is in scope. [ *Example:*
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct Base {
>    Base* p;
> };
>
> template <class T> struct Derived: public Base<T> {
>    typename Derived::Base* p; // meaning Derived::Base<T>
> };
>
> template<class T, template<class> class U = T::template Base> struct Third { };
> Third<Base<int> > t; // OK: default argument uses injected-class-name as a template
> ```
>
> *—end example* ]

I haven't found anything to indicate that this doesn't apply in the *ctor-initializer*, so I'd say that this is a compiler bug.

My stripped-down testcase [fails in GCC 4.1.2](http://codepad.org/faB14asJ) and [GCC 4.3.4](http://ideone.com/awtPS) but [succeeds in GCC 4.5.1 (C++11 mode)](http://ideone.com/tSWdI). It seems to be resolved by [GCC bug 189](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189); in [the GCC 4.5 release notes](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.5/changes.html):

> G++ now implements [DR 176](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#176). Previously G++ did not support using the
>   injected-class-name of a template base class as a type name, and
>   lookup of the name found the declaration of the template in the
>   enclosing scope. Now lookup of the name finds the injected-class-name,
>   which can be used either as a type or as a template, depending on
>   whether or not the name is followed by a template argument list. As a
>   result of this change, some code that was previously accepted may be
>   ill-formed because
>
> - The injected-class-name is not accessible because it's from a private base, or
> - The injected-class-name cannot be used as an argument for a template template parameter.
>
> In either of these cases, the code can be fixed by adding a
>   nested-name-specifier to explicitly name the template. The first can
>   be worked around with -fno-access-control; the second is only rejected
>   with -pedantic.

---

My stripped-down testcase with Qt abstracted out:

```
template <typename T>
struct Base { };

struct Derived : Base<Derived> { // I love the smell of CRTP in the morning
   Derived();
};

Derived::Derived() : Base() {};
```

Comment: As I understand he needs to add a template parameter to the Foos' Base class initialization as such:Foo::Foo(int someValue, QObject *parent)
   : Base<T>(someValue, parent)
{}

Comment: @Neox: Why? Why is the base's _injected-class-name_ not sufficient?

Comment: I believe this is a [link to the bug report](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=189) which has been fixed from gcc 4.5

Comment: @Jesse: Seems you're right, since it refers to DR 176. The bug description didn't seem pertinent to me, but I guess it's the same issue manifested in a quite different scenario.