# CRTC without default constructor

Tags: c++, crtp, icc

I'm having some trouble figuring out if this is a problem with my compiler:

```
class A
{
public:
    A(int i) {}
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int i) : A(i) {}
    T test() {return T(10);}
};

class C : public B<C>
{
public:
    C(int i) : B(i) {}
};

int main()
{
    C c(5);
}
```

> error: argument list for class template "B" is missing

This code seems to compile correctly in Visual Studio 2012, but it isn't working on icpc 9.1 (which I have to use for this project).

Comment: You mean `C(int i) : B<C>(i) {}`

Comment: @Jarod42: That would probably solve the problem, but the language does not require it.

Comment: both [g++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cc676b7593dd8ee8) and [clang++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08b15e65010e25c6) will compile as is.

Comment: `Class A` could be removed, right?

Comment: Seems to be a compiler bug: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887864/template-base-constructor-call-in-member-initialization-list-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct.

A possible workaround for *icpc* is to fully specify the base class:

```
C(int i) : B<C>(i) {}
```