# Multiple Inheritance from two derived classes with templates and constructors

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm following the example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254673/multiple-inheritance-from-two-derived-classes), however I am using templates and calling a constructor of one of the derived classes. The following code works without templates but when included I am not sure why I get the following error:

```
: error: no matching function for call to ‘AbsInit<double>::AbsInit()’
     NotAbsTotal(int x) : AbsInit(x) {};
                                   ^
```

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class AbsBase
{
    virtual void init() = 0;
    virtual void work() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class AbsInit : public virtual AbsBase<T>
{
public:
    int n;
    AbsInit(int x)
    {
        n = x;
    }
    void init() {  }
};

template<typename T>
class AbsWork : public virtual AbsBase<T>
{
    void work() {  }
};

template<typename T>
class NotAbsTotal : public AbsInit<T>, public AbsWork<T>
{
public:
    T y;
    NotAbsTotal(int x) : AbsInit(x) {};
};    // Nothing, both should be defined


int main() {
  NotAbsTotal<double> foo(10);
  cout << foo.n << endl;

}
```

Comment: @TavianBarnes ahaha thanks! make an answer please

Comment: This should work. But maybe my dupe is wrong as it should have been fixed in GCC 4.5, which massively predates C++14. What is your compiler and version?

Comment: And compilation command.

Comment: `AbsInit<T>` is a dependent base class. `AbsInit` is an injected class name within the scope of `AbsInit<T>` itself, but since the scope of `AbsInit<T>` is not examined, the only `AbsInit` that can be found in the first phase of name lookup is a class template name (when searching the global scope), not a type referring to some specific instantiation of `AbsInit<T>`

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: `C++11: 14.6.1/3` appears to say the opposite in an example. It's a shame you didn't actually read the potential dupe before re-opening this!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit nah, it presents an example using a qualified name lookup, here we have unqualified name lookup. it means that you can type `NotAbsTotal(int x) : NotAbsTotal::AbsInit(x)`, but still not `NotAbsTotal(int x) : AbsInit(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass a *template-argument* (in this case, `T`) to the base *template-class*.

Change this

```
template<typename T>
class NotAbsTotal : public AbsInit<T>, public AbsWork<T>
{
public:
    T y;
    NotAbsTotal(int x) : AbsInit<T>(x) // You need to pass the template parameter
    {};
};
```

Comment: This is surprising. `AbsInit` is supposed to be an accessible name, referring to `AbsInit<T>`. No?

Comment: Ah, turns out I've been over this before: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8887864/560648

Comment: Although, it was supposed to be fixed in GCC 4.5, which massively predates C++14 ... hmmm ...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, reading your answer now. But if template base class names are injected by default, how will the compiler resolve something like this. `template <typename T> class A : B<int>, B<float> .... { A() : B()  /*which of the B<>? */  {}  };` ??

Comment: Well that would be ambiguous obvs and you'd have to use the full typename.

Comment: The injected name thing fails on recent versions of clang and gcc. For Clang 3.8.0 [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc8a968191975476). And for gcc 6.1.0 [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/033b5a6909bfa1c6) ...

Comment: Innnntteresting. Could you post that on the original question plz?

Answer (score 2):

In the below snippet...

```
template<typename T>
class NotAbsTotal : public AbsInit<T>
{
    NotAbsTotal(int x) : AbsInit(x) {}
};
```

... `AbsInit<T>` is a [*dependent base class*](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#type-4):

> A *dependent base class* is a base class that is a dependent type and is not the current instantiation.

... and it is attempted to be referred to using an unqualified [*injected-class-name*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup#3) (`AbsInit`), but:

> The injected-class-name of a class (Clause [[class](http://eel.is/c++draft/class)]) is also considered to be **a member of that class for the purposes of name hiding and lookup.**

... however, [[temp.dep]/p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep#3):

> In the definition of a class or class template, **the scope of a dependent base class** ([[temp.dep.type]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.dep.type)) **is not examined during unqualified name lookup** either at the point of definition of the class template or member or during an instantiation of the class template or member. [ *Example*:
>
> ```
> typedef double A;
> template<class T> class B {
>   typedef int A;
> };
> template<class T> struct X : B<T> {
>   A a;              // a has type double
> };
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> — *end example* ]

As such, `AbsInit` cannot be bound to an *injected-class-name* which exists in the scope of `AbsInit<T>` itself. That name, left alone, is subject to [*unqualified name lookup*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup.unqual), and refers to a class template found in the global namespace.

To avoid the error or enforce desired name resolution, append a template argument list to the class template name `AbsInit`:

```
NotAbsTotal(int x) : AbsInit<T>(x) {}
//                          ~~^
```

or use a qualified name:

```
NotAbsTotal(int x) : NotAbsTotal::AbsInit(x) {}
//                   ~~~~~~~~~~^
```

Remark: once the base class is not dependent (i.e., a concrete type is used, e.g., `AbsInit<int>`), you can use the unqualified form of the injected-class-name.