# Compiler Error When Calling Base Constructor when both Base and Derived are Templated With Derived Type Parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I am struggling to understand why the following code does not compile:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
    public:
        Base(int a){}
};
template <class T>
class Derived: public Base<T>  {
    public:
        Derived(int a): Base(a){}
};
int main(){}
```

On my compiler (gcc 5.4.0 with C++ 11) this outputs the error message

```
error: class 'Derived<T>' does not have any field named 'Base'
         Derived(int a): Base(a){}
```

I see that this is somewhat similar to [Template base constructor call in member initialization list error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8887864/template-base-constructor-call-in-member-initialization-list-error), though that test case actually compiles for me while this one does not: The main difference seems to be that both `Base` and `Derived` use the same type parameter. Additionally, it compiles fine if I explicitly add the type parameters or I give an explicit scope for base, as in

```
template <class T>
class Base {
    public:
        Base(int a){}
};

template <class T>
class Derived: public Base<T>  {
    public:
        Derived(int a): Derived::Base(a){}
};

int main(){}
```

What's going on? Am I misunderstanding when injected class names may be used?

Comment: Why Not Derived:Base <T>(a)?

Comment: Note that [it works as is with MSVC](http://rextester.com/DXHHO32475), because MSVC does name lookup differently than GCC.  Clang emits the same error as GCC, though, albeit worded differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The injected class name `Base` is a member of the class `Base`, and since the base class is dependent, its scope is not searched during unqualified name lookup. As such, using the name `Base` will only find the class template, not the injected class name of `Base<T>`. That is why you must write `Base<T>`.

`Derived::Base` works because it causes name lookup to be postponed until `Derived` is instantiated.